# Accessing values from prop.table() in R

Tags: r

I have a probability table as follows:

```
prop.table(table(h[[10]]))

         1         12         15         16          3          9 
0.20000000 0.30000000 0.10000000 0.13333333 0.20000000 0.06666667
```

I then converted it to matrix using:

```
probData <- data.matrix(prop.table(table(h[[10]])))
```

Now I need to run the condition such as:

```
if (probData[row,column] > 0.2){

  print(print name of that column eg 1,12,15,16)  

}
```

probData[row,column] gives me the probability.The problem is I am not able to access the column names (1,12,15,16) from their respective probabilities.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @RichardScriven Want to add it as an answer?

Comment: Whoops. The review console hid it from me :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could call the names directly from the `prop.table` with a vectorized condition.

Here's an example with the `mtcars` data

```
(p <- prop.table(table(mtcars[1:10,3])))
#
#  108 140.8 146.7   160 167.6   225   258   360 
#  0.1   0.1   0.1   0.2   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.2 
# 
names(p[p > 0.1])
# [1] "160" "360"
```

Or in one line, you could do

```
names((p <- prop.table(table(mtcars[1:10,3])))[p > 0.1])
# [1] "160" "360"
```